# Multiple when conditions is not working Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, case, multiple-conditions

my data set looks like this

[raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLV3T.png)

I wrote this code:

```
flightData2015.select("*",when(flightData2015['count']>200,'above200')
                  .when(flightData2015['count']>400,'above400').otherwise("below").alias("new count")).show()
```

output :
[red line does not follow my logic, I want to know why the second "when" condition is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvaFc.png)

Comment: Try changing the order of first 2 `when` or add the upper bound for the first when condition.  Right now, if a value is 500, the first condition is met, and second condition won't be evaluated.

Comment: Exactly like Emma said. if you already met the count > 200 criteria you will never even check for the other when caluse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the condition ">200" will satisfy items that are greater than 400 also, so that is why the second when is not used.

Secondly, a nested when otherwise clause should work.

```
when(flightData2015['count']>400,'above400').otherwise(when(flightData2015['count']>200,'above200').otherwise("below"))
```